Custom consensus engines that use miner.BuildPayload?
For Proof-of-Stake Ethereum, a new "consensus path" was added, that makes it possible to do validator selection before starting to produce a block, rather than in proof-of-work Ethereum where a miner always starts to produce a new block the moment a new one has been added. It seems "Catalyst API" is a part of this new path, and that the validator selection is done first externally, and that it then activates miner.BuildPayload to run the block production (here in catalyst/api.go). I'm very interested in building a custom consensus engine that relies on generateWork path rather than commitWork, as my engine ideally does validator selection before block production. The current version of my engine (link) is using commitWork though. I'm interested in if there are any custom consensus engines that use BuildPayload path (so I could maybe look at them and learn a thing or two. )
